# How to get the color of a widget text, and set it as the color of another widget

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have two widgets

first, a `QLineEdit` that has a stylesheet (assume not accessible or changeable) that sets the color of the text to some color (e.g., red).

second, `QLabel` that has a default text color (e.g., black)

How can I get the color of the text in the `QLineEdit`, and set it as the color in the `QLabel`

```
l1 = QLineEdit()
color_to_be_set= l1.palette().highlight().color().name() # this approach is giving the wrong color

q1 = QLabel()
q1.setText("the text")

# then set the new color
"Trial#1 (Not working at all, not changing the color)"
palette = q1.palette()
palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText,QColor(color_to_be_set))
q1.setPalette.....

"Trial#2, gives the wrong color"
q1.setStyleSheet("color:{}".format(color_to_be_set))
```

Comment: `highlight()` returns the background color of the selection. Try with `text()` or `windowText()`.

Comment: I tried both `text()` and `windowText()`, but awkwardly giving the wrong color of the text inside the `QLinEedit`. Is there any way to extract this information from the stylesheet, something like `l1.styleSheet().QLineEdit.color()`

Comment: @zero There's no API to read stylesheet properties from a widget.

Comment: @ekhumoro that's not *completely* true. The basic `color`, `background-color`, `selection-color` and `selection-background-color` properties, if set, are always installed on the widget palette with their relative color roles. The catch is that the widget has to be polished.

Comment: @zezo starting from your basic example, you will only get the default color for the application palette, as the widget has no stylesheet set (nor is added to any parent). If the stylesheet is set on a parent, you need to add the widget as its child in order to enable it. Also, you need to call [`ensurePolished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) before getting it, if you've not shown it yet.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot. Yes, i expected that I am getting the default color for the app each time I call `pallete`. I will try the child and `ensurePolished()` tricks.

Comment: @musicamante Okay - but I only meant there's no *dedicated* API. And in any case, I've always thought it best to respect the user's preferences in this area. Whenever I've made the mistake of trying to impose a style, there always seems to be at least one user with some weird theme or widget-style who gets inconsistent results. Has this situation changed in Qt recently? My assumption was that it remains a mug's game, because there's still no completely general, unified approach that is *guaranteed* to work on all platforms (that is, other than e.g. writing your own cross-platform plugin).

Comment: @ekhumoro I completely agree. Obviously, when custom plugins and styles come in the way, things get weird and inconsistent (sometimes even with the default ones). But, since (AFAIK) QStyleSheetStyle *does* become the "main" style whenever any stylesheet affects the widget, we know for sure that those basic colors are always set as overrides for the widget's palette upon polishing. Then, I concur, the problem remains: if a property is not explicitly set, the underlying style will use the palette as it wants, with widgets possibly using the role they want, even inconsistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained in comments, there's no public API to access properties set by stylesheets, and I sincerely doubt there could be any (at least, with the current implementation, including Qt6).

That said, there is some level of access to those properties, but it only works for the following:

- `background` and `background-color` (which are the same);
- `color`;
- `selection-background-color`;
- `selection-color`;
- `alternate-background-color`;

Whenever any of the properties above is set, the palette of the widget is altered with the following *palette color roles*:

| [QSS property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties) | [QPalette role(s)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) |
| --- | --- |
| `background`, `background-color` | `Base`, `Button`, `Window`, [`backgroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#backgroundRole)<sup>*</sup> |
| `color` | `Text`, `ButtonText`, `WindowText`, [`foregroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#foregroundRole)<sup>*</sup> |
| `selection-background-color` | `Highlight` |
| `selection-color` | `HighlightedText` |
| `alternate-background-color` | `AlternateBase` |

<sup>The ***** values are references to the widget class definitions (for instance, QPushButton normally uses `Button` as foreground role). They may be overridden by their respective setter functions.</sup>

Also, those properties only support the QSS [`Brush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#brush) types: plain colors, gradients or [`palette(<role>)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole). No pixmaps here!

Remember that in order to get proper access to those properties, the widget **must** be *polished*, which means that, if the widget has not been *ever* shown yet, calling [`ensurePolished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) is mandatory:

> Ensures that the widget and its children have been polished by QStyle (i.e., have a proper font and palette).

This means that any new Qt widget created without *any already polished* parent will use the **system** palette.

Consider the following:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('* {color: green;}')
source = QWidget()
# source.ensurePolished() # leave this commented for now
color = source.palette().windowText().color()
target = QWidget(styleSheet='background: {}'.format(color.name()))
target.show()
app.exec()
```

Then uncomment the fifth line, and see the result.

---

Now, there are a few catches.

When a stylesheet is set, any widget *affected* by it gets it's `style()` overridden by a *private* QStyleSheetStyle. That style is not exposed by the API and completely takes control over the style set for each affected widget.
But not always.

Take this snippet:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('* {background-color: black;}')
topLevel = QTextEdit()
topLevel.show()
parent = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(parent)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
layout.addWidget(QTextEdit())
parent.show()
app.exec()
```

With my current style (oxygen), the two backgrounds are slightly different:

[image: screenshot of the above code]

On the left there's the `topLevel` widget, on the right the `parent`. As you can see, the underlying style still has some level of control.

This is an important aspect that has to be kept in mind, and trying to override it with a QProxyStyle won't be enough: the QStyleSheetStyle will "take control" and completely ignore the overridden functions, except for a very few like `drawItemText()`. Any other function will be called on "the C++ side" implementation, for which there's no useful override in the python bindings.

Also, whenever the underlying style is still used internally by the QSS, the result is that the color properties will be used just like any QPalette: they are *reference* colors, not the actual ones. Any widget will use the style implementation, which might use different color roles, or completely alter the color depending on the situation.

Whenever the default style is used (even through QStyleSheetStyle modifications), the palette is just a reference, not unlike a physical palette: give the same basic color palette to two styled painters, and they will use its colors in different ways. The actual color shown to the user might be slightly or even completely different and possibly ignored.

---

Concluding, the following aspects are of utmost importance:

- just created widgets will use the default palette;
- there is no access to border properties, nor margins and paddings (with the last two also depending on the inherited style);
- top level widgets might behave differently;
- the style might not completely adhere to the colors set (and even ignore them);
- palette colors are references: the style might use a role for an unexpected purpose, or completely ignore it; some common styles use the `Button` role for item view headers, other use the `Window` role;
- while normally respected, the above color properties might be altered by the style, just like any palette;
- basic QSS color properties can be properly accessed only after the widget has been polished: `ensurePolished()` has to be called, which normally happens after the first visibility change and any `setStyleSheet()` call that affects the widget (see [`QStyle.unpolish()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#unpolish) and [`QStyle.polish()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#polish));
- QPalette uses QBrush for any of its roles and groups, which could be any of the following: a QColor, a QGradient or a QPixmap; this means that if a palette role uses a gradient or pixmap, the returned `color()` will be *invalid*, etc.;
- `background-image` does **not** update the palette (in fact, it's not listed in the table above); the same goes for `border-image` (as said above, there is no access to border properties);
- the `fusion` style is (usually) the most reliable style to be used for extended stylesheet implementation; when unsure or getting unexpected behavior, use `QApplication.setStyle('fusion')` or `widget.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`;
- OS styles potentially override drawing with private pixmaps in order to respect the standard OS appearance;
- complex widgets require *full and explicit* values for their properties; **never** set generic properties (aka, no selectors) for parent widgets or the application<sup>[1]</sup>, including QComboBox, QScrollBar and all QAbstractScrollArea subclasses (including item views);

So, considering all this, as long as a standard QStyle is used and the widget is polished, the roles explained in the above table *should* return the colors set in the supported properties of any stylesheet, including inherited ones.

But you can *never* be sure about that, and you always have to be aware of it.

<sup>[1] in the code examples above I *did* use generic stylesheets, but that was on purpose and for simplicity; that practice is usually *highly* discouraged for normal usage. Always use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) when setting stylesheets for parents and complex widgets (see above).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation