# How do I get current background color for QlineEdit widget in Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How do I get the background color of a QlineEdit widget in pyqt5?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you change the color in some way and you want to get that color? Can you clarify what you need this for?

Comment: @musicamante...I did it using stylesheet. I then want to be able to go back and check with qlineedit widgets have had a color change

Comment: I suppose the only solution is to get the current stylesheet and try to parse it with a **regex** for instance. If only you can alter the stylesheet, then you certainly know what logic is needed to parse it and get back the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, QLineEdit uses the `Base` palette role for its background and also uses that role for its [`backgroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#backgroundRole).

Since basic properties of stylesheets set some color roles for the local widget palette<sup>[1]</sup>, the solution is to use that along with the role:

```
background = label.palette().color(label.backgroundRole())
print(background.name())
```

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231822) to know how QSS colors can alter a widget palette.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To complete my comment, this regex `"(?<=background-color:)(.*?)(?=[;\}])"` can do the job for simple cases (see simulation I did here: https://regex101.com/r/SEB9hQ/1). You can improve it to fit your needs.
The captured group should be `strip()`ed to get rid of spaces.

Comment: What about stylesheets set for the application or a parent, or even stylesheets using multiple selectors?