# 50% Transparent background for my calendar widget

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to make the background in the selected area(the white area behind day numbers) transparent, but I couldn't find any way. I would appreciate it if someone could show me how to do this. ty

[image]

When I try the first code it goes black,

[image]

I tried some codes but it either went all black or didn't do anything

```
QWidget#qt_calendar_calendarview {
        background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 128); /* 50% transparent gray */
    }
```

or

```
calendar_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 128);")
calendar_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

I want something like this so the app background can be visible under the calendar.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "transparent" (in relation to what, the underlying widgets or the whole window) what are you referring to with "selection"? Also, please provide a clear [mre] of the above attempts.

Comment: Hey ty for your time. I updated the post and made it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This was tricky, and it required quite some digging in the Qt sources.

## tl;dr

The problem is caused by a specific behavior of the peculiar QStyle internally set to a widget whenever it is affected by a stylesheet, and the way the embedded model gets the background of date cells.

This is technically a bug, and can only be worked around with a hack that involves a custom item delegate and a "dummy" model.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CalendarFixModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, calendar):
        super().__init__(calendar)
        self.calendar = calendar
        calendar.currentPageChanged.connect(self.updateCurrentPage)
        self.view = calendar.findChild(QTableView)
        self.updateCurrentPage()

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return self.background
        return self.fakeIndex.data(role)

    def updateFakeIndex(self, source):
        self.fakeIndex = source
        if (
            (source.row() == 0 and self.calendar.horizontalHeaderFormat())
            or 
            (source.column() == 0 and self.calendar.verticalHeaderFormat())
        ):
            # vertical/horizontal header
            self.background = source.data(Qt.BackgroundRole)

        else:
            year = self.year
            month = self.month
            day = source.data(Qt.DisplayRole)

            if source.row() > 4 and day < 15:
                # next month
                if month == 12:
                    month = 1
                    year += 1
                else:
                    month += 1

            elif source.row() < 2 and day > 15:
                # prev month
                if month == 1:
                    month = 12
                    year -= 1
                else:
                    month -= 1

            date = QDate(year, month, day)
            fmt = self.calendar.dateTextFormat(date)
            if fmt.hasProperty(fmt.BackgroundBrush):
                self.background = fmt.background()
            else:
                fmt = self.calendar.weekdayTextFormat(date.dayOfWeek())
                if fmt.hasProperty(fmt.BackgroundBrush):
                    self.background = fmt.background()
                else:
                    self.background = None

        return self.index(0, 0)

    def updateCurrentPage(self):
        self.year = self.calendar.yearShown()
        self.month = self.calendar.monthShown()


class CalendarDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, calendar):
        view = calendar.findChild(QAbstractItemView)
        self.fakeModel = CalendarFixModel(calendar)
        super().__init__(view)
        view.setItemDelegate(self)

    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        super().paint(qp, opt, self.fakeModel.updateFakeIndex(index))


app = QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('''
    QMainWindow {
        border-image: url("landscape.png");
    }
    QCalendarWidget {
        background: transparent;
    }
    QCalendarWidget > #qt_calendar_calendarview {
        /* background for calendar dates */
        background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 127);
        /* 
            default background for headers, can be overridden by using
            QCalendarWidget.setHeaderTextFormat()
        */
        alternate-background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 127);
    }
''')

calendar = QCalendarWidget()
CalendarDelegate(calendar)

window = QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(calendar)
window.show()

app.exec()
```

## Explanation

The black background is indirectly caused by an unwanted result of the QStyle (a private subclass of QCommonStyle, QStyleSheetStyle) set on any widget that is affected by a style sheet.

### Qt Style Sheets (QSS) and widget palette

When a main color property is set in a style sheet, the above QSS style actually updates the palette of the widget, which is the reason for which `setPalette()` shouldn't be used along with style sheets (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71207148) to know more about how style sheets affect the widget's palette).

Most importantly, the `background` property also sets the color for the `Base` palette role, which is the color normally used as background for "entry widgets" like line edits, spin boxes or item views.

But there's a catch, an important aspect I didn't realize until a few days ago, and that affects only certain composite widgets; specifically, *composite widgets* that *embed* another widget that may need some level of transparency. Among these widgets, there are scroll areas (the embedded widget is the [*viewport*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#details)), which are all widgets that inherit from QAbstractScrollArea, including the embedded QTableView of QCalendarWidget.

When a non-opaque background is set for these widgets, the style actually ignores the background, setting a "null brush" (a QBrush with a `NoBrush` [style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#style)) for the background roles (see the post linked above) of the palette. This is done to make the embedded widget "transparent" and allow the QSS style to draw the background appropriately when necessary.

Note that a non-opaque background can mean:

- a color that has an alpha value less than 255;
- a pixmap that has an alpha channel (or a mask)

So, one of the results of the above is that whenever a scroll area has a non-opaque background, it sets the `Base` palette role to an invalid brush.

Normally, this is fine: a `NoBrush` palette role will result in the widget not painting its background. But even such a brush will always return a valid [`color()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#color), which, by default, is black.

### Anatomy of QCalendarWidget

QCalendarWidget is probably the most complex widget in the standard Qt library, at least upon its creation (excluding the QDateTimeEdit related classes that use it). Other than its "tool bar" (which also embeds a QSpinBox for the year selection and a popup QMenu to select the current month), it also includes a QTableView to show dates, week numbers and week days, which in turn uses an internal QAbstractTable model subclass and a custom QItemDelegate.

Whenever any "cell" of the calendar widget (headers included) is being drawn, the table view asks its delegate to paint that cell, which does what delegates normally do: query the `data()` function of the model for a given QModelIndex in order to draw the contents of the cell.

The model is completely dynamic: no value or reference is stored, and `data()` always tries to retrieve the cell of the index. It may be a header (week number/day), or a real date.

Then, the model creates a QTextDateFormat instance and eventually *merges* it with the format of the requested cell, in order to return basic text format aspects (colors, font and even the tooltip).

If the cell corresponds to an actual date (it's not a header), then it calls [`dateTextFormat(date)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#dateTextFormat-1) and merges it accordingly, and returns the required values based on the `role` of `data()`.

Now, the problem comes from the fact that, by default, `dateTextFormat()` uses the current palette of the view and just returns it's [`color()`]; if no color is specified for a date, it returns the "background" brush of the palette.

Also, the model's `data()` only returns the `color()` of the background brush, which means:

- if the brush uses a gradient or a pixmap, the returned color is black (even if it's not a valid color)
- as explained above, a non-opaque color set as a background of a complex widget such as QTableView will result in a `NoBrush` style, but still a black color;

Finally, since the model's `data()` just calls [`merge()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html#merge) on the initial QTextChaFormat, and `merge()` does *not* check if the color is valid, the returned `color()` will actually be a "valid" black.

### The workaround

As it happens in most cases when dealing with Qt item views, the solution is to use a custom delegate.

The QTableView used by QCalendarWidget uses a basic QItemDelegate (instead of the more advanced QStyledItemDelegate). Unfortunately, for reasons I don't understand yet, [`drawBackground()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#drawBackground) is the only drawing function provided by that class that is not *virtual*, so it cannot be overridden.

One possibility is to "inject" a custom delegate, but, in order to provide proper painting and ensure that it respects the default visualization, a work around is required.

Since the `drawBackground()` function above calls the model `data()` of the cell, we can *illude* the delegate into painting an index from a different model.

The trick is to create a dummy model that returns the `data()` of the original model index, unless the `BackgroundRole` is requested. Each request to `data()` will be unique, so we can safely return a single index for it.

Here is how all this works:

- each call from the `paint()` function of the delegate will always be followed by further calls to the `index.data()` (with different roles) for the same index;
- the dummy model is a QAbstractListModel subclass: since we only need one index for each `paint()` call, we just need the first index of a mono-dimensional model to provide that data (similarly to a proxy model);
- when `paint()` is called, we call a custom function of the model that always returns the *only* index (first row and column) but, in the meantime, also checks for the background:

  - if the index is part of a "header", it just sets the default background based on the "source index" `BackgroundRole`;
  - otherwise, it gets the current date for that index; QCalendarWidget always has 6 rows and 7 columns (plus headers), even for months that only have 5 or even 4 full weeks (such as February 2021 for locales starting on Mondays), which may start on the second row (for months starting on the first day of week) and/or ends on the fifth (when the month only has 28 days or starts with a non-first day of the week); this means that if we get a "day" (numeric) value greater than 7 in the first two rows, it belongs to the previous month, and if the value is smaller than 7 beyond the second row, it belongs to the next month;
  - it checks if that date has a custom text format (set with [`setDateTextFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#setDateTextFormat) with a valid background set ([`hasProperty(QTextFormat.BackgroundBrush)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html#hasProperty)) and eventually sets a temporary `background` attribute based on it:

    - if it has it, `background` is the QTextCharFormat.background()
    - if it doesn't, checks if the calendar has a [`weekdayTextFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#weekdayTextFormat) set for that day of week, and eventually sets it;
    - if it doesn't, it sets `background` as `None` (reverting to the default delegate paint);

Then, the dummy model will return the above `background` for a `Qt.BackgroundRole` request, otherwise will return the `data(role)` of the "proxy" index previously set.

### Implementation

The above solution requires the mentioned dummy model and custom delegate, but also a properly written style sheet.

The delegate class takes the calendar widget as argument in its constructor, finds the view, and sets itself as main delegate in the view; it also creates an internal dummy model that sets the calendar as its parent object.

The dummy model also creates an internal "cache" for the current shown year and month in order to improve the performance of its behavior.

The style sheet requires that:

- the QCalendarWidget background is `transparent`;
- the QTableView sets a proper background;
- (optional) an `alternate-background-color` is set as default, but it can be overridden by calling [`QCalendarWidget.setHeaderTextFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#setHeaderTextFormat);

Note that the dates outside of the current month may require further checking, because if you want to show a non opaque background, those dates may become partially or completely invisible; QCalendarWidget normally uses the view's palette `Disabled` group and `Text` role for dates outside the current month; this can be altered in the implementation by creating a further `if/elif/else` block.

Here is a screenshot of the above implementation:

[image: Screenshot of the above example]

Comment: To anyone reading, I just realized that *real* culprit is the internal model of QCalendarWidget (the fact that its `data()` function returns the text format `color()` background, instead of the actual brush): the style sheet aspect is, in reality, a "colluded" actor, and fundamentally a symptom. I filed a report on the Qt bug tracking system ([QTBUG-120724](//bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120724)) with a more appropriate description of the problem. The description in this answer should to be fixed accordingly, but that has to be done properly; I will hopefully update it as soon as possible.

Answer (score -2):

The value for the alpha channel must be between `0.0` and `1.0`. For 50% transparency the snippets should look like this:

**CSS**

```
QWidget#qt_calendar_calendarview {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5); /* 50% transparent gray */
}
```

**Javascript**

```
calendar_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);")
calendar_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

See more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.php

Comment: Hey, ty for your answer. I tried both but still had the same problem first one makes the calendar completely black and the second one does nothing!

Comment: "Javascript"?!?

Comment: Also, the OP is asking about Qt Style Sheets, which are only *based* on standard CSS, and following the CSS2.1 specification, which only accepted integer values (0-255) or percentages, and only the `rgb()` definition (no alpha). Qt extended it to `rgba` on their QSS implementation, [but still following the same syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#color), so only integers or percentages.